# How to return data back to Main view from bootstrap modal popup(present in partial view) search using asp.net mvc and jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a textbox(which will display product name) and search button in my form.On clicking search button, i have successfully opened a bootstrap modal popup with grid.Inside grid each row has select button.
On clicking select button i want to close the modal pop up and refresh the textbox with product name which i have selected in grid using jquery ajax.

```
 function (column, row) {
            return '<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" ' +
                   'title="Select" href="javascript:void(0)" data-action="Select" data-row-id="' + row.ProductId + '">' +
                        '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" aria-hidden="true"></span>' +
                    '</a> '  }
```

Comment: Show your code what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be needing ajax to do what you require.This can be easily achieved using javascript/jQuery.
you would be having a button like :

```
<button onclick="buttonclick('value')">Select</button>
```

Just place the value in **argument of the onclick function** that you require to fill in the textbox after clicking on the button.Then make a javascript function like :

```
function buttonclick(param){
     //you can access that value using the variable param.
     //Or you can give any name of your choice.
     $('textboxID').val(param); //to put that value in your textbox.
     $('#modalID').modal('toggle'); //you can also use 'hide' instead of 'toggle' to close your modal.
}
```

If you do not want to pass the value in the argument of the function then you can also set that value in the **data-attribute** of the tag and access that in the function like :

```
<button data-select='value' onclick="buttonclick(this)">Select</button>

function buttonclick(param){
     // access that data attribute using data()
     var value = $(param).data('select');
     $('textboxID').val(value); 
     $('#modalID').modal('toggle');
}
```

Comment: In my grid i have four columns and one of the column is ProductName.I want to retrieve that name.

Comment: place that ProductName in place of the **value**  given in the `<button>` while forming that grid and you are good to go.

Comment: You can use onclick for an anchor tag too like:                              `<a onclick="buttonclick('+row.ProductName+')">`                               You should learn the basics  of javascript/Jquery , make an effort to find the answer and if not found then put a post here over stackoverflow.

Comment: Thankyou,you have solved my problem.